# using guard inside where bindings in Haskell language

Tags: haskell

i am a newbie in haskell language and i would like to use *guard* inside *where binding* but i get error:
Not in scope: `x'
Failed, modules loaded: none.

```hs
describelist'' :: [a] ->String
describelist'' xs = "the list is : " ++ what xs
    where what xs
              | xs == "" = "empty list "
              | xs ==[x] = "singleton"
              | otherwise = "list more than or equal two elements"
```

i think that my code is right but error always appear,

Comment: `xs == [x]` makes no sense (as guard), since you did not define `x`, this is a pattern.

Answer (score 2):

`xs == [x]` makes no sense as *guard*, since you did not define `x`, this is a pattern. The same for `xs == ""`, since it is not said that `xs` is a `String`, it can be an empty list of `Int`s for example.

You thus should use pattern matching:

```
describelist'' :: [a] -> String
describelist'' xs = "the list is : " ++ what xs
    where what [] = "empty list"
          what [_] = "singleton"
          what _ = "list more than or equal two elements"
```

Comment: thank for your help, now bit understand my missunderstand. To get more clearly view about this concept i have one more question is that: " *guard* is used for pattern matching with specific value? and this is the different between *guard* and *pattern matching*

Comment: @LeoPkm: a guard is an expression that evaluates to a `Bool`, it can not introduce new variables.

Comment: @LeoPkm When you have a value of a given type (e.g. a list) and you need to test that value you should first try pattern matching using the constructors (`[]` and `(x:xs)`, for lists). That will not only check which form has your value but also dissect the value into its parts (defining `x` and `xs`). If that's not enough you can also add guards. I'd suggest not using guards unless you can't find any solution using pattern matching.